# MySQL Queries - Check a Record

Tags: mysql

anyone can help me implement this

Given that i have a txt file and have successfully parsed them into an array.
Column Headers are ID, Names, Gender.
I want to check whether the Names are already in the table.

Say i have 5 rows of Data

```
0 | Rod | M  
1 | Dex | M  
2 | Fay | F  
4 | Dan | M  
5 | Lis | F
```

currently im looping into the array and using SELECT to check if the item Names already exists

is there a way were i can pass All 5 Names in a query and it will return records
a. those found  the Table
b. Not found in the table

thanks for responding to my Question. The IN Operator will cut my queries to just one trip to the server, then will just loop through the results.

Comment: if your file looks always like above, you could check the file if it contains "| Rod |" (for ex.), otherwise you could take a hashtable where your key is the name. if the hashtable contains the key......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible for `b`, possible for `a`

```
select * from your_table
where your_column in('Rod','Dex','Fay','Den','Lis');
_______________________________________^ assume Den is not match with Dan
```

The above queries should return 4 matches (with Den not matched with Dan).
You can compare against your array again.
Those without matching record (Den) will be the `NOT found` record